# select columns based result of query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that brings back only columns that are a result of another query.  The subquery queries a table listing of column names.  The table is huge, several hundred column names that I need.  That's why I don't want to manually type in all the column names.

The query goes something like this:

```
select (
         select columname
         from columname_table
         where save_data = 1
        )
from data_table
```

Comment: So you have  multiple columnname_tables? One for each column?

Comment: @DogEars +1 cause you made me laugh

Comment: In MS SQL server management studio you can drag from the  object explore into the query window to automatically type all the column names.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL:

```
select
    AUX.*
from ( 
    select columname
    from   columname_table
    where  save_data = 1
) AUX
```